# How to disable the warning 'define' is not defined using JSHint and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, jshint

I uses RequireJS AMD in my project. When i run jshint on my project, it throws error like

In AMD Scripts

```
 'define' is not defined.
```

In Mocha test cases

```
 'describe' is not defined.
 'it' is not defined.
```

How to remove this warning in jshint?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Just to expand a bit, here's a `.jshintrc` setup for Mocha:

```
{
  ....
  "globals"   : {
    /* MOCHA */
    "describe"   : false,
    "it"         : false,
    "before"     : false,
    "beforeEach" : false,
    "after"      : false,
    "afterEach"  : false
  }
}
```

From the [JSHint Docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) - the false (the default) means the variable is read-only.

If you are defining globals only for a specific file, you can do this:

```
/*global describe, it, before, beforeEach, after, afterEach */
```

Comment: we can use `{"mocha": true}`  2.5.1+ https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1330

Comment: @bendytree do you know if i can add these rules for some files / folders not global?

Comment: @Gobliins Bohdan's comment above. Add that line as the first line of your mocha test file and it will enforce the rule for that file only

Answer (score 18):

```
jshint: {
  options: {
    mocha: true,
  }
}
```

is what you want

Answer (score 12):

To avoid the not defined warning in jshint for the javascript add comments like:

```
/*global describe:true*/
```

[Options](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options)

Answer (score 8):

Add this in your .jshintrc

```
"predef" : ["define"]   // Custom globals for requirejs
```

Comment: predef is depreceted, use globals

Comment: @JonathanAzulay I didn't find any deprecation note at http://jshint.com/docs/options/#predef . I think Global can be used for custom Global JavaScript e.g angular, $, jQuery etc and predef can be used for implicit global objects like window, document, console etc

Answer (score 6):

late to the party, but use this option in your `jshintrc`:

```
"dojo": true
```

and thou shall rest peacefully without red warnings...

Answer (score 6):

If you are working on node js. Add these two lines in the beginning of your file

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";
```

Comment: This question is about _JSHint_.

Answer (score 3):

[Read the docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) and search for `/*global`

Comment: From the [JSHint GitHub example](https://raw.github.com/jshint/jshint/master/examples/.jshintrc): `"unused" : true,     // true: Require all defined variables be used`

Comment: That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to run JSHint in WebStorm with Mocha, as I am, go into:

WebStorm > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Code Quality Tools > JSHint

Scroll down to "Environments" and make sure you have selected the checkbox to enable "Mocha" which will set up the definitions for JSHint for Mocha for you.