# JSHint behave differently in Webstorm and Grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, webstorm, jshint

I have created a new service with Grunt using the angular-generator and then reformatted the code with WebStorm **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>** as the tabs / spaces seem to be different.

Then when using Grunt and the task JShint complains I get the following errors:

```
app/scripts/services/poteservice.js
  line 11  col 13  Expected '}' to have an indentation at 15 instead at 13.
  line 14  col 13  Expected '}' to have an indentation at 15 instead at 13.
```

Another strange issue is that I found that I can enabled JSHint inside WebStorm but then I get issues like

```
 JSHINT: angular not defined
 
    and

 Use the function form of use strict
```

How can I make everything play together nicely i.e. WebStorm and Grunt etc.?

I have the WebStorm plugin for Angular installed.

Comment: you have to make sure indentation is set to the same value in webstorm and in .jshintrc file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should configure WebStorm to use the same JSHint file as Grunt.

Go to `Project Settings -> Javascript -> Code Quality Tools -> JSHint` click **`Enable`** and reference to the **`.jshintrc`** in your Project.

Second, you should add this two lines of code at the top of all your JavaScript files:

```
/* global angular */
'use strict';
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I also had to change the indent from 2 to 4 in jshint file and all works... thanks for that.. It seems to be working

Comment: You can also use globals property for defining angular in .jshintrc file like `"globals" : { "angular": false}`