# Why the module not recognized in my project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend, web-frontend

I start a project in angularjs, to learning about it by practice.

I insert to `<html>` this directive `ng-app="ComplibaryApp"` .

And of course include the js angular files. at the end of the `<body>`.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="js/factory.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

At the body i have : `<div ng-view ></div>`

Why at my files , conroller.js/config.js/factory.js , the module not recognized?

[image]

Comment: I believe that is just intelli-sense issue, I would also add a space between your `=angular`. What environment are you using? I think its just the IDE saying it can't find that function or module.

Comment: @TheLazyChap , I add a space, and still... I use Webstrom and i have the angular plugin. any idea?

Comment: are you using any JS linting tools such as `jshint`, `eslint` or `jslint` in your project? Take a look at this question and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666090/webstorm-angular-is-not-defined that person had similar issue like yourself. Watch the screencast link of her problem to see if its the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Angular globally defined for your IDE ? Otherwise it won't recognise any of the angular functions.

*on a side note, in your `LoadData` function you can just `return` the `$http`, this is also a promise (no need to create your own)*

Comment: In other projects it works fine with angular. what you mean if my angular defined in my IDE ? I have the plugin Angular selected in my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the settings in Webstorm for either jshint or jslint, depending on which is turned on for you.
In jslint, you can add a predefined for angular