# jslint not recognising angularjs

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code, jslint

this is the code:
angular.module('kontrol', ['ngRoute'])

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', '$provide', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')

  $routeProvider.when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/pro.html',
    controller: 'kontrola'
  })
}])
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: am using angular in vscode but 'angular' is underline red saying that angular is not define: 'export namespace angular'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSHint (r10): 'angular' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837139/jshint-r10-angular-is-not-defined)