# difference between globals and predef in .jshintrc?

Tags: node.js, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

What the difference and purpose of having both of them in the .jshintrc? When I want to add a variable to be ignored, which one is the best one I should use? Also I can't find 'predef' in http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems like `predef` is deprecated and you should use `globals` instead.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260779/how-to-disable-the-warning-define-is-not-defined-using-jshint-and-requirejs)

Comment: well, [this](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/1178) pull request does imply it has been deprecated, but [jshint doc](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) is still using `predef` in the example.

Answer (score 5):

At JSHint Doc page http://www.jshint.com/docs/ `"predef"` is mention for use inside `.jshintrc` file,
wile word "globals" is used only once for inline directive (those that are inside `.js` files)

So examples would be :

- inside `.jshintrc` file

  ```
  "predef" : [ // Extra globals
               "angular",
  ]
  ```
- inside `.js` files

  ```
  /* global app: false */
  ```

So it would be better to use different words when doing the same but in different places.

Comment: For inline comment in js files, should it be `/* globals app: false */` (plural form) or `/* global app:false */` (singular form).  [JSHint doc](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#globals) did not provide a specific example for the inline configuration for this option.

Comment: globals can also be used in .jshintrc, So an difference in where they are used is stricly user preferance. global is a typo anywhere.