# How to define custom package in angular with out jshint warning?

Tags: angularjs, jshint

I've just installed moment.js into my angularjs app.

But the jshint keep warning that moment is not defined.

```
  public/js/services/notifications.js
 16 |        console.log(moment.locale('fr'));
                         ^ 'moment' is not defined.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable the warning 'define' is not defined using JSHint and RequireJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260779/how-to-disable-the-warning-define-is-not-defined-using-jshint-and-requirejs)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add moment to the globals configuration of your .jshint file

```
    {
      ..,
      "globals": {
         ..,
         "moment" : false
      }
    }
```