# Atom linter / es-lint disable some warnings

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, atom-editor, eslint, linter

I am writing some tests with wdio and mocha framework and my linter packages https://atom.io/packages/linter and https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint display some problems (see comments):

```
describe('[On Board]', () => { //describe is not defined
  before(() => {  // before is not defined
    browser.waitUntil() //browser is not defined
    ....
```

The undefined stuff will be taken care of the wdio / mocha Testrunner, so i would like to tell my linter / es-lint packages to ignore this problem.

Is this possible?

Comment: As you are not defining these variable in your file so your linter is not aware of it. You need to include mocha namespace in your JS file. Hope it will fix the issue.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal you are right, the answer solved my problem

Comment: Ok. I am adding it as an answer, please accept it to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Either to include the namespace where `describe` and other variables are defined.
2. Or you can update .jshintrc to make linter aware that you are using mocha framework and ignore the errors.
   Link that can be helpful: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260779/how-to-disable-the-warning-define-is-not-defined-using-jshint-and-requirejs)